# Fortran "Cannot assign to a named constant at (1)" in if statement

Tags: if-statement, fortran

Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
if (z.le.zstart) then
   if (y.ge.((6.95*wg_y2)/5)).and.(y.le.((12.55*wg_y2)/5)) then
      indexmedia=nd
   end if
end if
```

For context,

`zstart` is an arbitrary line of constant `y`.

`wg_y2 = 5e-6`

And for some reason it doesn't like the `(y.ge.((6.95*wg_y2)/5))` bit, as the (1) was placed at the end of that bit.

I had a suspicion that it doesn't like anything that isn't an integer in the if statement but I changed 6.95 to 7 and 12.55 to 13 and it still didn't like it. Perhaps it needs to end up resolving to an integer?

I need these parameters to end up to

6.95 < y < 12.55 though.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

When compiling the code (not nice as I didn't declare the variables!, but that isn't the problem here so I abstain from it to keep it a bit small):

```
program tst
if (z.le.zstart) then
   if (y.ge.((6.95*wg_y2)/5)).and.(y.le.((12.55*wg_y2)/5)) then
      indexmedia=nd
   end if
end if
end
```

one gets the error:

```
aa.f90:3:29:

    if (y.ge.((6.95*wg_y2)/5)).and.(y.le.((12.55*wg_y2)/5)) then
                             1
Error: Cannot assign to a named constant at (1)
aa.f90:6:3:

 end if
   1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
```

This is due to a missing pair of round brackets in the line:

`if (y.ge.((6.95*wg_y2)/5)).and.(y.le.((12.55*wg_y2)/5)) then`

which should read

`if ((y.ge.((6.95*wg_y2)/5)).and.(y.le.((12.55*wg_y2)/5))) then`